# PutObject into directory Amazon s3 / PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload my files inside specific directories that I created on my amazon s3 storage. I always uploaded the files on the "absolute path" of my bucket doing something like so:

```
$s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'ContentType'   => $mime,
            'Key'           => $localImage,
            'ACL'           => 'public-read',
            'SourceFile'    => $localImage,
            'CacheControl'  => 'max-age=172800',
            "Expires"       => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years")),
            'Metadata'      => array(
                'profile' => $localImage,
            ),
        ));
```

How can I define where this file should be uploaded on a given directory?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You must include that information in the "Key" parameter. S3 isn't actually a filesystem, it's more like a big (hash table) associative array. The "Bucket" is the name of the hash table, and the "Key" is the key (e.g., `$bucket[$key] = $content`). So all path/directory information must be a part of the "Key".

```
$localImage = '/Users/jim/Photos/summer-vacation/DP00342654.jpg';
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'my-uniquely-named-bucket',
    'SourceFile' => $localImage,
    'Key'        => 'photos/summer/' . basename($localImage)
));
```

Comment: How can i debug this? that file is uploaded or not ?

Comment: @Vivek use $insert = $client->putObject([ than echo $insert['Body'];

Answer (score 3):

thank you Jeremy Lindblom, this is my python example that worked for me.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
data = open('/home/briansanchez/www/red-hat.jpg', 'rb')
s3.Bucket('briansanchez').put_object(Key='www/red-hat.jpg', Body=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated code according to the latest SDK of AWS:-**

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'bucket name of S3',
    'Key' => 'pawan-trying',
    'SourceFile' => 'local image path or document root image path ',
    'ContentType' => 'image',
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata' => array(
        'param1' => 'value 1',
        'param2' => 'value 2'
    )
        ));
```